# Is there a way for pandas rolling.apply to enter a dataframe into the function

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have code as below:

```
def fn(x):
    ...
df.rolling(length).apply(lambda x: fn(x))
```

I want the function to take a subset of the dataframe as input. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way can be the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(5, 15, 5), 
                   'b': np.random.randint(5, 15, 5), 
                   'c': np.random.randint(5, 15, 5)})

def fn(x):
    return x.sum()

r = df.rolling(3)

[fn(x) for x in r]
```

Output:

```
[a    10
 b    13
 c    14
 dtype: int64,
 a    19
 b    27
 c    19
 dtype: int64,
 a    33
 b    38
 c    24
 dtype: int64,
 a    29
 b    37
 c    16
 dtype: int64,
 a    32
 b    30
 c    23
 dtype: int64]
```

Comment: Does this mean that if I want to access 3 columns of data at once it is not possible?

Comment: The approach I suggest works for an arbitrary number of columns. I have just simplified it -- please, see the edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a way, while it doesn't really pass a portion of the df as an argument the df can be acquired from there.

```
def fn(x):
    df_frac = df.iloc[x.index.start: x.index.stop]
    return ...

df.rolling(length).apply(lambda x: fn(x))
```